# Using PLCameraController class in iPhone OS 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Has anybody used `PLCameraController` class in iPhone OS 4.0?

Can you please share example how you are using it? Can you also share interface declaration for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to use the private PLCameraController class in iPhone OS 4.0, given that you are now provided with raw video frames from the camera and the ability to control camera properties using AVFoundation's new AVCaptureDevice, etc. classes.

I recommend watching the [WWDC 2010 session](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) 409 "Using the Camera with AV Foundation", where all of this is demonstrated.

Comment: I need to access raw photo data after it is taken from camera, so I can get EXIF data from it. Is this available in the AV Foundation? I can not seem to find out.

Comment: @Boran Milankovic - Look to the +jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation method on AVCaptureStillImageOutput: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureStillImageOutput/jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation: It returns NSData containing a JPEG image and its EXIF metadata.